# Parsing JSON with multiple representation in the same attribute

Tags: json, rust, serde

I'm relatively new to Rust, and even more so to Serde, so I'm having trouble finding out if this is even doable. I have a JSON file which has two different representations for the same key:

```
"coordinates": [
  [
    [
      121.423364,
      24.9913596
    ],
    [
      121.4233327,
      24.9912977
    ],
  ]
]
```

and this:

```
"coordinates": [
  [
    121.4472492,
    25.0052053
  ],
  [
    121.4466457,
    25.0028547
  ]
]
```

There is a two dimensional array and a three dimensional array representing ways in the same attribute. This makes the file hard to serialize.

Here is the code that I implemented:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Geometry {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "string_or_number", rename = "type")]
    geometry_type: Value,
    #[serde(default, skip_serializing_if = "Vec::is_empty", rename = "coordinates")]
    geometry_coor: Vec<Coordinates>,
    #[serde(default, skip_serializing_if = "Vec::is_empty", rename = "coordinates")]
    geometry_coor2: Vec<Vec<Coordinates>>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Coordinates {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "string_or_number")]
    longitude: Value,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "string_or_number")]
    latitude: Value,
}

fn string_or_number<'de, D>(de: D) -> Result<Value, D::Error>
where
    D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let helper: Value = Deserialize::deserialize(de)?;

    match helper {
        Value::Number(n) => {
            println!("{:#?}", n.as_f64().unwrap().to_string());
            Ok(Value::Number(n))
        }
        Value::String(s) => Ok(json!(s)),
        _ => Ok(json!(null)),
    }
}
```

I have trouble in `struct Geometry` which serializes the file of coordinates.

Are there any ways that I can deal with this kind of form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got [help from the serde-rs developer](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/issues/473):

> I would recommend using an [untagged enum](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged) to represent a coordinate array that can be 2d or 3d.
>   [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e1f4a4e688b3adc08ccded3c4a571cdb&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Here is the code after modification:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Geometry {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "string_or_number", rename = "type")]
    geometry_type: Value,
    #[serde(default, skip_serializing_if = "Vec::is_empty", rename = "coordinates")]
    geometry_coor: Vec<Coordinates_form>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Coordinates_form {
    #[serde(skip_serializing)]
    OneD(Coordinates),
    #[serde(skip_serializing)]
    TwoD(Vec<Coordinates>),
    #[serde(skip_serializing)]
    ThreeD(Vec<Vec<Coordinates>>),
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Coordinates {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "string_or_number")]
    longitude: Value, 
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "string_or_number")]
    latitude: Value,
}

fn string_or_number<'de, D>(de: D) -> Result<Value, D::Error>
where
    D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let helper: Value = Deserialize::deserialize(de)?;

    match helper {
        Value::Number(n) => {
            println!("{:#?}", n.as_f64().unwrap().to_string());
            Ok(Value::Number(n))
        }
        Value::String(s) => Ok(json!(s)),
        _ => Ok(json!(null)),
    }
}
```